# Representing accents in strings

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am working in a Python program with Javascript and DB. I have been having some problems managing the written accent marks (á,é,í,ó,ú). First my program displays some text inputs so the user writes information. When the user clicks an "ACCEPT" button, a javascript takes that information and sends it to another python program which is going to save that information on a database. The next time the user enters, the info saved on the database would be displayed instead of the text inputs.

My problem is when the information has any accent mark on it. At first I though it was a problem with javascript so I start working on replaces functions. Then i saw that the information was saved on the database with the accent mark, so the problem is not with the javascript function, or the database.

The information is taken from the database and it displays the accent marks very well. Then a javascript takes that value and if I put an alert with that value, it displays the accent mark very well. That javascript sends that value on a URL with AJAX to another python program. This python receives that value but when print it, it is modify. The accent mark is not longer displayed, but a little square. I receive the values with this code (I have been using this many times):

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
area = form.getfirst("area")
```

So i started tasting again the python replace function to change that character to the apropiate accent mark. I been trying something like: `area.replace("\u00e9","é")` for (é). But it does not work.

I also have this in my programs: `# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-` which works for special characters.

I need to find out the way python represents the accents so I can replace them.

Comment: I'd recommend against using any `coding` declaration other than utf-8.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Indeed - please read the link given by @thg435, and resort to using utf-8 both on javascript, html and Python code.

Comment: @mauguerra: He means you should *only* use utf-8 as your encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to back up here.

Set a coding of utf-8 (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`), and use an editor that works with unicode.

Declare your constants, and generally operate with, unicode strings like `u'hélas'`.

As if by magic, accents will work (as long as your database handles unicode correctly; ensure that it does).

Comment: But i already have the coding of utf-8 (# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-). do i need to change something there?

Comment: @mauguerra: In your question you say that you have the coding set to iso-8859-1. utf-8 is the way to go, but make sure your editor is operating in utf-8 mode.

Comment: I am using an editor which operates in utf-8 mode. Do you know what else could it be? Thanks a lot

Comment: @mauguerra: no, how could I? You need to work out which part of your application (as a whole, that is including all components) is processing the text incorrectly. It sounds like you're either having the problem in the browser or in your code which receives the data from the browser.

Comment: I just noticed that my problem with the iso-8859-1 only happens on Internet Explorer, on the other browsers works perfect.

Comment: @mauguerra: nevertheless, I suggest that you cease using non-unicode encodings.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is ok in the database but it looks scrambled to the python program, there might be a problem with the way the database connection is set up. I'd investigate that before you go rearranging your working environment. (But do read that Unicode reference as well).